# ADO.NET Entity Framework I can't see Foreign Key Property in Model

Tags: ado.net

I have 2 table. In first table I have a Foreign Key link to second table's primary key.

(second)Personel and (first)Istbl are my tables.

In personel table I have PersonelID , PersonelName, PersonelSurname.

In Istbl table I have IsID, PersonelID, xx, xx, xx, going like this.

I can't see PersonelID  in EF Model Viewer. I also can't see it in code screen.

Is there any example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF v1 hides foreign keys because it views them as persistence artifacts not important to the domain model. See [here](http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/2007/09/11/EntityDataModelAssociationsWheresMyForeignKey.aspx) for a discussion.

EF v2, shipping with .NET 4, will include much better support for foreign keys in the model.

Answer (score 2):

You can get foreign key value with something like this

```
object foreignKey = istblObject.PersonelReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing your datamodel?  Have you created the model from the database, if so, try recreating it, if you have updated your database model.

Comment: i can see it from second table Personel if i create new Personel Class but i cant see it in Istbl Class.I wanna give it a value while inserting data but intellisense is showing me Personel class not PersonelID property.So i cant add a value for it and my application giving me error